# Make option layout with checkbox and then div inline

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to layout a voting poll on a webpage.

The poll should be displayed as a radio button and then a `<div>` containing all of the relevant poll data. Within the poll data `<div>`, I need the option text on the left and then the percentage on the right. Here is a basic visual representation of the layout -

```
/---------------------------------------------------\
|/-------\/----------------------------------------\|
||       ||/------------------------\/------------\||
|| Radio ||| Option text            || Percentage |||
||       ||\------------------------/\------------/||
|\-------/\----------------------------------------/|
\---------------------------------------------------/
```

I've almost got this (I think!), but the widths are wrong, with the radio button taking up too much space. They should be only as wide as required, with the `<div>` containing the rest of the data taking up the rest of the space directly to the right.

Could someone please suggest how I can alter my CSS/HTML to make the layout as I desire?

Here is the link to the code - http://jsfiddle.net/D4cqL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a width to your display-container :

```
.poll .poll-option-container .poll-option-display-container {
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    float: right;
    width:93%;
}
```

I also add a line-height to checkbox-container for the vertical align :

```
.poll .poll-option-container .poll-option-checkbox-container {
    height: 36px;
    line-height:36px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 1px;
}
```

Hope it helps

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8RBCK/)**

Comment: That would work in this instance I suppose, as the overall space taken is set and not dynamic. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
.poll-option-checkbox-container input {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```